# Pop-up A map to get user's location in Django

Tags: html, django, popup

I'm Implementing a simple web app using Django, I want to get user's location by clicking on a Google map, but I don't want him to open another page to open the map while registering, I want the map to popup inside the same page he is registering at, can you tell me please the best way to achieve such a popup? I want a cohesive trick so I can replace the map on such a popup and put any HTML instead, thank you in advance :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

display a `<div>` using JQuery with `position:absolute` and use top and left properties to move the div into position. set padding internally, then use google maps API to spawn a map in there. Use JS to post the placemark to a hidden url of your site. then use django GIS to store the positional information

- http://www.jquery.org <- JQuery
- http://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/javascript/ <- Maps API
- https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/gis/ <- GeoDjango

If you have a specific question about the use of these tools, ask again.